# Updating a Svelte store value onMount doesn't work

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

In one of my Svelte components, I'm trying to reset the count value in the store to 0 upon mounting the component.

Here's how I'm attempting to do it:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    
    const myStore = writable({
      count: 1
    });
    
    function updateCount() {
    $myStore.count = 0;
    console.log("my store:", $myStore);
  }
    
  onMount(() => {
    updateCount();
    console.log("my store on mount:", $myStore); // count will be 1
  });
    
</script>

<!-- count is 1 -->
<h1>{$myStore.count}</h1>
```

However, upon rendering the component, I notice that the count value remains 1 instead of being updated to 0 as intended. Even though the updateCount() function is called inside the onMount hook, the console logs inside the hook show that the count is not updated.

For now to fix it I have it like this:

```
onMount(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      updateCount();
    }, 1);
  });
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't replicate the issue. Your code, as written, works as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```js
function updateCount() {
    myStore.update(v => ({ count: v.count + 1}));
}
```

### Explanation

Svelte stores don't track changes in individual properties of the stored object, and therefore they won't update listeners when these change.  The correct way to communicate a change is to completely replace the value via update or via the assignment (=) operator.  This would look like this:  `$myStore = { count: $myStore.count + 1};`.  I prefer the one above to this one, though.